# Ngrx selectors not emitting new values

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to get a single objet back from the server on page reload in a resolver, but the selector that's supposed to get that object form the store, after it's been saved there, does not emit a new value. Why is that? 
The log in the selector is called twice, the 2nd time with new value, but for some reason they're not being emitted in the resolver. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

My reducer file :

```
    export interface GroupState extends EntityState<Group> {
    topicsLoaded: {
        topic: string,
        count: number,
        groupsLoaded: number
    }[];
}

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Group>();

export const initialGroupState = adapter.getInitialState({
    topicsLoaded: []
});

export const groupReducer = createReducer(
    initialGroupState,
    on(GroupActions.getTopicGroupsSuccess, (state, action) => {
        let oldTopics;
        let newTopics;
        // Check if 1st batch of groups have already been loaded //
        const oldGroupsLoaded = state.topicsLoaded.find(g => g.topic === action.topic);

        if (!oldGroupsLoaded) {
            // Add topic to group entity //
            newTopics = [...state.topicsLoaded];
            newTopics.push({
                topic: action.topic,
                count: action.count,
                groupsLoaded: action.groupsLoaded
            });
        } else {
            // Update group entity //
            const index = [...state.topicsLoaded].indexOf(oldGroupsLoaded);
            oldTopics = [...state.topicsLoaded];
            oldTopics[index] = {
                ...state.topicsLoaded[index],
                groupsLoaded: state.topicsLoaded[index].groupsLoaded + action.groupsLoaded
            };
        }
        return adapter.addMany(action.groups,
            {
                ...state,
                topicsLoaded: oldGroupsLoaded ? oldTopics : newTopics
            });
    }),
    on(GroupActions.getSingleGroupSuccess, (state, action) => {
        const newTopicLoaded = [...state.topicsLoaded];
        newTopicLoaded.push({
            topic: action.group.topic,
            count: action.count,
            groupsLoaded: 1
        });
        return adapter.addOne(action.group, {
            ...state,
            topicsLoaded: newTopicLoaded
        });
    })
);

export const {
    selectAll,
} = adapter.getSelectors();
```

Resolver :

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        const topic = route.queryParams['topic'];
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        return this.store
            .pipe(
                select(isTopicLoaded, { topic }),
                withLatestFrom(
                    this.store.pipe(select(selectTopicGroups, { topic })),
                    this.store.pipe(select(selectGroupById, { id }))
                ),
                tap(([loaded, groups, group]) => {
                    if (!loaded && !this.isLoading) {
                        this.isLoading = true;
                        this.store.dispatch(GroupActions.getTopicGroups({ topic, pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 20 }));
                        this.store.dispatch(SpinnerActions.startSpinner());
                    }
                    /* On page refresh groups will not be loaded from the store
                        so we need to fetch that single group from server
                    */
                    if (id && !group && !this.groupLoading) {
                        this.groupLoading = true;
                        this.store.dispatch(GroupActions.getSingleGroup({ groupId: id }));
                    }
                    console.log(loaded, groups, group);

                }),
                filter(([loaded, groups, group]) => {
                    if (id) {
                        return group !== undefined ? true : false;
                    } else {
                        return !!loaded;
                    }
                }),
                map(([loaded, groups, group]) => {
                    if (group) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    // Offer to create a group if the array is empty //
                    if (groups.length === 0) {
                        this.router.navigate(['/groups/create'], {
                            queryParams: {
                                empty: true,
                                topic
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                }),
                first(),
                finalize(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.groupLoading = false;
                }));
    }
}
```

Selectors:

```
export const selectGroupsState = createFeatureSelector<GroupState>('groups');

export const selectAllGroups = createSelector(
    selectGroupsState,
    fromGroups.selectAll
);

export const selectTopicGroups = createSelector(
    selectAllGroups,
    (groups, props) => {
        const topic = props.topic;
        return groups.filter(g => g.topic === topic);
    }
);

export const isTopicLoaded = createSelector(
    selectGroupsState,
    (state, props) => {
        const topic = props.topic;
        return !!state.topicsLoaded.find(g => g.topic === topic);
    }
);

export const selectGroupById = createSelector(
    selectAllGroups,
    (groups, props) => {
        console.log(groups, props);
        const id = props.id;
        return groups.find(g => g._id === id);
    }
);

export const totalGroups = createSelector(
    selectGroupsState,
    (state, props) => {
        const topic = props.topic;
        const group = state.topicsLoaded.find(g => g.topic === topic);
        return group ? group.count : 0;
    }
);

export const groupsAlreadyLoaded = createSelector(
    selectGroupsState,
    (state, props) => {
        const topic = props.topic;
        const group = state.topicsLoaded.find(g => g.topic === topic);
        return group ? group.groupsLoaded : 0;
    }
);
```